# Getting ContentType in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

i have the following code in c#. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{

    // If ContentType is not expected to be application/json, then return XML
    if ((context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType ?? String.Empty).Contains("application/json"))
    {
        new JsonResult { Data = this.Data }
            .ExecuteResult(context);
    }
    else
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(500))
        {
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlTextWriter.Create(
                stream,
                new XmlWriterSettings()
                {
                    OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                    Encoding = UTF8,
                    Indent = true
                }))
            {
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), IncludedTypes)
                    .Serialize(xmlWriter, this.Data);
            }
            // NOTE: We need to cache XmlSerializer for specific type. Probably use the 
            // GenerateSerializer to generate compiled custom made serializer for specific
            // types and then cache the reference
            new ContentResult
            {
                ContentType = "text/xml",
                Content = UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray()),
                ContentEncoding = UTF8
            }
                .ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to return a json or a xml result depending the request. The problem is that i get `context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType = ""` when i run it.

Is there a way to make the application know that the request is "application/json"?

I'm returning this result object in a controller method called GetGoogleMapsMarkers:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:1939/API/Google/GetGoogleMapsMarkers",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {

            alert(data);

        }
    }
});
```

Help me please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added

`data: { },`

to the ajax call and it worked.... it's weird but it made it work...

Answer (score 2):

Unable to reproduce. Here's what I tried:

Result:

```
public class TestResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var ct = context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write(ct);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        return new TestResult();
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("foo")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
</script>
```

The AJAX call resulted in the correct request content type to be fetched.

Comment: Hi, i tryed what you did but now i'm getting 'text/html' not 'application/json'...